# itemize doesn't work with multicolumn in tabularx

Tags: tabularx, itemize, multicolumn

I am learning Tex. I am trying to span an unordered list across 2 columns, but it doesn't work, and I can't figure out the problem. It works fine for a regular string of text. Here is the sample code that I can't get working:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    Col 1 & Col 2\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{A long sentence that successfully spans across 2 cols.}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \item An item in Itemize that should span across 2 cols.
      \item Another item in Itemize that should also span across 2 cols.
    \end{itemize}}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! For me, it works. Do you have any error message? Or warning?

Comment: @Bernard, I had 2 warnings:
```
Underfull \hbox (badness 5787) in paragraph at lines 19--19
Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--20
```
but I don't think these are related to the problem that I had. David's answer below solved my problem. Strange that it worked for you as-is. Would this have to do with the version of tabularx or TeX I am using (TeX Live 2021)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `\linewidth` as well (the manual probably ought to mention that)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    Col 1 & Col 2\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{A long sentence that successfully spans across 2 cols.}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax\linewidth=\hsize}X|}{
    \begin{itemize}
      \item An item in Itemize that should span across 2 cols.
      \item Another item in Itemize that should also span across 2 cols.
    \end{itemize}}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @David, this worked. However, I didn't understand why I didn't have to do it for the normal text, but had to for the itemize.

Comment: @fishfin linebreaking is a tex primitive operation that only looks at `\hsize` latex maintains several lengths to control nested lists and indentation so an itemize within a quote within an enumerate knows how long the margins and text blocks are supposed to be, the main one of these is `\linewidth` that gets set in a p (so X) column to mach `\hsize` but if you change hsize and have a laetx display you should change `\linewidth` as well

Comment: Ok, so since `\hsize` is a primitive, changing that does not trigger change of `\linewidth` automatically, so the LaTeX engine continues to think it has smaller width. By manually forcing this change to `\linewidth`, it worked. So now I was wondering instead of `\hsize=2\hsize+2\...`, I could have directly done `\linesize=2\hsize+2\...`, but since I don't know much about internals of the `\hsize` primitive, for now I think I understand both `\hsize` and `\linewidth` need to be in sync. Thank you once again @David!

Comment: @fishfin no you need to set them both. `\setlength` or just \hsize=... or \linewidth=... is a very low level register assignmnt it just does the assignment specified and nothing else.